# Flask - Not bounded to current context

Tags: python, flask, celery

I am trying to write a class, ChangeBackStatusOnErrorTask which does exactly as its name implies.

```
class ChangeBackStatusOnErrorTask(Task):
  abstract = True

  def on_failure(self, exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo):
    server = Server.query.get(server_id)
    server.status = RemoteStatus.ERROR
    db.session.commit()


@celery.task(bind=True, base=ChangeBackStatusOnErrorTask)
def deploy_server(self, server_id):
  try:
    server.status = RemoteStatus.LAUNCHING
    db.session.commit()

    host = server.ssh_user + '@' + server.ip
    execute(fabric_deploy_server, self, server, hosts=host)

    server.status = RemoteStatus.LAUNCHED
    db.session.commit()
  except Exception as e:
    server.status = RemoteStatus.ERROR
    db.session.commit()
    traceback.print_exc()
    raise e
```

However, this code is not working due to the fact that ChangeBackStatusOnErrorTask is not bounded to my Flask context:

```
  File "/Users/vng/.virtualenvs/AutomataHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 367, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/vng/.virtualenvs/AutomataHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 622, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/vng/Dropbox/Code/Affiliate/AutomataHeroku/automata/server/tasks.py", line 59, in deploy_server
    server = Server.query.get(server_id)
  File "/Users/vng/.virtualenvs/AutomataHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 498, in __get__
    return type.query_class(mapper, session=self.sa.session())
  File "/Users/vng/.virtualenvs/AutomataHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 78, in __call__
    return self.registry()
  File "/Users/vng/.virtualenvs/AutomataHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 990, in __call__
    return self.registry.setdefault(key, self.createfunc())
  File "/Users/vng/.virtualenvs/AutomataHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2861, in __call__
    return self.class_(**local_kw)
  File "/Users/vng/.virtualenvs/AutomataHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 143, in __init__
    self.app = app = db.get_app()
  File "/Users/vng/.virtualenvs/AutomataHeroku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 957, in get_app
    'application not registered on db instance and no application'
RuntimeError: application not registered on db instance and no application bound to current context
```

## How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you try creating an app? `app = Flask(__name__)` in `tasks.py` before your class definition

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that you use sqlachemy and the flask-sqlalchemy extension. And that you  get your `db` object from some dedicated module and this object is also bound to the flask instance(please edit your question to clarify those point).

Inside your `app` module declare your celery config:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config[CELERY_BROKER_URL] = 'redis://localhost:6379'
app.config[CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND] = 'redis://localhost:6379'
```

Then inside your celery module you need to bound it to flask:

```
from celery import Celery
from app import current_app as app

def bound_celery(app): 
    celery = Celery(
        app.import_name,
        backend=app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'],      
        broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL']
    )
    celery.conf.update(app.config)    
    TaskBase = celery.Task 

    class ContextTask(TaskBase): 
        abstract = True 
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
            with app.app_context(): 
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery

 celery = bound_celery(app)
```

And finally use the `celery` created object to decorate your tasks:

```
@celery.task(bind=True, base=ChangeBackStatusOnErrorTask) 
def deploy_server(self, server_id):
    ...
```

Source: [flask doc](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/celery/)

Comment: I am currently using flask-celery which does something almost identical to what you mentioned: https://github.com/Robpol86/Flask-Celery-Helper/blob/master/flask_celery.py#L220 

So I think flask_celery already covers me in that aspect.

Comment: As the [doc](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/celery/) and the [flask-celery réalisme](https://github.com/ask/flask-celery/blob/master/README.rst) say, there is no need for an extension anymore. Using it will be at the risk of depending on a no longer maintain middleware. Anyway looking back at my answer, it seems wrong, the wrongly bound object is `db` not `celery`. Can you please share your full code ? So we can see how your db object is created and share.

Comment: @lee-pai-long You just made my day! I wished I found this doc earlier!